# Windows Azure Cloud Services for Students

Tags: azure, cloud

how can student use windows azure online services? can we use it for free? at least trial version, because we need to use it for IC project.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can get a **1-Month Free Trial Subscription**. The free trial has enough features you need to use as a student.

[Read the details of the available features in Free Trial](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/)

[Get Free Trial](https://account.windowsazure.com/signup?offer=ms-azr-0018p)

Cheers!

**Please note** while registering for free trial you need a valid credit/debit card and a transaction of $1 will be made to verify your card.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Web Sites is FREE up to 10 sites that run in "Shared mode" (limited CPU, memory, bandwidth, storage):
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/

It is pretty powerful for what you get to get started.

As mentioned above there is a FREE 90-trial.  Also if your school has a Microsoft partnership and provides MSDN Subscription access...you do get $3,700 / year of Azure for FREE.